# Uploadify - how to abort uploading?

Tags: uploadify

I have simple problem with Uploadify. Before upload starts, I want to check some criteria, it true - I want to abort uploading. The code below doesn't works properly, it uploads file even if I call the `uploadifyCancel`. How to fix it ?

```
$("#fileuploader").uploadify({
            uploader: '/Scripts/uploadify.swf',
            script: '/Upload/'
            fileDataName: 'file',
            buttonText:'upload',
            multi: false,
            sizeLimit: 369878,
            simUploadLimit: 1,
            cancelImg: '/Images/uploadify-cancel.png',
            auto: true,
            onOpen:function(event,ID,fileObj) {
                var found = $('#uploaded-files-table tr[some-attr="1"]');

                if($(found).length == 0){
                    $('#list').attr('disabled','disabled');
                } else {
                    $("#fileuploader").uploadifyClearQueue();
                    $("#fileuploader").uploadifyCancel(ID);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which version your using But I  could do it below way.
I need stop file upload based on file extension

```
'onAddQueueItem':function(file, e) {
 if (!(/\.(gif|jpeg|png|pdf)$/i).test(file.name)) {
$($this).data("uploadifive").removeQueueItem(file, 0, 10);
    file.skip = true; //This skip property stop uploading file
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$("#fileuploader").uploadifyCancel(ID);` code is working properly.  If you add in an onComplete and an onAllComplete, neither one of these events gets hit signifying that cancel event worked.

The problem is that uploadify inherently starts uploading the file BEFORE the onOpen event occurs.  Check here, it looks like they were having the same issues with modifying script data on onOpen http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/5611/uploadifysettings-not-posting-new-script-data/p1

I did have some success canceling files if they were over 600-700KB in size with both `$("#fileuploader").uploadifyCancel(ID);` and `$("#fileuploader").uploadifyClearQueue();`.  I think this has to deal with the speed of the upload.  Because these were larger files, the cancel event had time to fire before the upload finished.  On a live server, not on your local host, the upload times would be slower so MAYBE there wouldn't be a problem with the events canceling in time.  I wouldn't risk it though.

A possible workaround is to include a secondary button on the page that starts the upload and remove the `auto: 'true'` from your uploadify init.  This way, you could check whatever values you need to before the upload begins.

Answer (score 0):

use `onSelect` of uploadify to check.

You can do like this:

```
$("#fileuploader").uploadify({
            uploader: '/Scripts/uploadify.swf',
            script: '/Upload/'
            fileDataName: 'file',
            buttonText:'upload',
            multi: false,
            sizeLimit: 369878,
            simUploadLimit: 1,
            cancelImg: '/Images/uploadify-cancel.png',
            auto: true,
            'onSelect': function (file) {
                       if(file.type==".zip")
                       {//do something
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          //cancel upload
                         }
```